# How to pass extra flags to the configure utility to a package from the Debian repositories?

Tags: debian, compiling

The case is this: There exists a package on the official Debian repositories. This package won't build on my system because it requires configure flags that it was not packaged with.

To solve my issue, I need the same process as running `sudo apt-get install`, the only difference being that some extra set of flags are added in the `./configure` step.

My non-solution:

1. Run `sudo apt-get build-dep` to install dependencies.
2. Use `apt-get source` to download source code
3. Edit the `debian/rules` file
4. Add `export DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS = --some-flag --some-other-flag=option` immediately below the shebang line(the first line in the document)
5. Run `debuild -b -uc -us` to build the package
6. Check the output to make sure that configure has the correct flags (the package is installed but not built at this point)

When I check the output in step 5, I don't see the flags that I want so I think I did something wrong.

Possible errors: maybe I am making a syntax mistake that I am not aware of or I am misunderstanding how the build process works.

(In my specific case I am trying to the spl-dkms and I am trying to point it to the right kernel headers, so if anyone knows an easier way I would appreciate it)

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was adding flags to `dh_auto_configure` under the `override_dh_auto_configure` target. I had to find this myself (and it seemed to work for me), but I don't know if this is the most robust/elegant solution.

Comment: This is the right way of going about things; there is no default environment variable to provide extra configuration flags.